# Unconventional Open Graph story -- how to build?

Tags: api, web-applications, facebook-opengraph, social-networking

My client has a fashion-related site that will have a feature showing various celebrities and photos of their "looks". Users can click a button to indicate whether they think these looks are a "hit" or a "miss".

With that in mind, here's what we want to publish on our users' timelines:

> [user] thinks [celebrity photo] is a hit on [website].
>   [user] thinks [celebrity photo] is a miss on [website].

Facebook OG is set up in such a way that it really only supports things like "[user] has [action] an [object]." Right now I have a fairly convoluted way of accomplishing the above story. I have a "think" action and "celebrity photo miss" and "celebrity photo hit" objects. I'm then more or less able to tweak the text to fit the above. Then I'll have to have URLs in the site to reference those objects (e.g. /photos/celebrityname/look1/miss and /photos/celebrityname/look1/hit. Those URLs will essentially be copies of the photo at /photos/celebrityname/look1.

On top of it all, I don't even know if I can convince Facebook to approve such a setup. There's nothing deceptive or tricky about it, but it's not exactly usage as they intended.

So before I put this all together, can anyone enlighten me on other ways of accomplishing this that are simpler? It would be so much easier if there were some sort of template-driven method of putting together the story text, but as far as I know no such thing exists.

**EDIT:** I was able to accomplish this using the above method, and I was able to convince Facebook to approve it. It's a little hackish but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that unless you've got a huge ad budget, you are not going to get a custom solution for this, sorry.

You'll have the fit the 'user `action` an `object`' model

Why not use something like: user `likes` a `celebrity photo on BlahBlah`?

Comment: What does ad budget have to do with it? Do you mean development budget? Seems to me that this is either possible or not possible, as the FB OG API is the same for everyone no matter how big or small your budget is. Also, the semantics of this feature don't fit the "like" action.

Comment: "On top of it all, I don't even know if I can convince Facebook to approve such a setup. There's nothing deceptive or tricky about it, but it's not exactly usage as they intended." In terms of your influence in getting Facebook to approve a custom setup, yes, the amount of money you give Facebook per month for Ads very much matters. Like so: you spend more money, you get a sales contact person. That sales contact person can get you on a phone call with an engineer, that can approve your setup, etc. So yes, more money can get you custom setups on Facebook.